# How to write Join and where in Spark DataFrame (Converting SQL to DataFrame)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to write SQL Query into DataFrame

**SQL Query**

```scala
A_join_Deals = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM A_transactions LEFT 
JOIN Deals ON (Deals.device = A_transactions.device_id) WHERE 
A_transactions.device_id IS NOT NULL AND A_transactions.device_id != '' AND 
A_transactions.advertiser_app_object_id = '%s'"%(adv_id))
```

**Code written up to now**

```scala
val A_join_Deals = Deals.join(A_transactions,Deals("device") === A_transactions("device_id"),"left")
```

Now I am stuck how to write the where Clause.

Any Suggestion or Help is Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try as below

```
val A_join_Deals = Deals.join(A_transactions,Deals("device") === A_transactions("device_id"),"left")
      .where(A_transactions("device_id").isNotNull && A_transactions("device_id") =!= "" && A_transactions("advertiser_app_object_id") === s"${adv_id}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but how to pass a variable [%(adv_id))] ? in the condition  in Data-frame ?

Comment: You can use like function for spark which is silmilar to % in sql.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thanks for your suggestion but we dont want to use %sql sparksql since we need to register the dataset as temp table which is taking a lot of Memory since we have data in TeraByte

Comment: @Bhavesh If `adv_id` is a scala variable in scope, you can do `A_transactions("advertiser_app_object_id") === Deals(s"$adv_id"))`

Comment: @DanieldePaula Thanks for your suggestion i will try to implement it and see once again Thank you for your help DanieldePaula, ShankarKoirala and Ramesh

Comment: @Bhavesh the `A_transactions.advertiser_app_object_id = '%s'"%(adv_id)` means that `advertiser_app_object_id` is ending in string present in `adv_id`. Is this correct?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan afaik, `'%s'"%(adv_id)` will take a value from a variable called `adv_id` and put in place of `%s`. So the query is actually testing if the value in `advertiser_app_object_id` is equal to the value in the variable `adv_id`. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do

```
where(A_transactions("device_id").isNotNull &&
   A_transactions("device_id") =!= "" && 
   A_transactions("advertiser_app_object_id") === s"${adv_id}%")
```

This works if `adv_id` is a variable and not Column

Hope this helps!